# Oracle 10g XE error on delete - ORA-00903: invalid table name

Tags: sql, oracle10g

When I issue this select statement in the Oracle web console it returns all the rows in the table:

```
select * from sbus;
```

However when I issue this delete statement I receive an error message - ORA-00903: invalid table name

```
delete * from sbus;
```

This table is very simple:

```
create table sbus
( id            number(11)          not null,
  sbu           varchar2(75 char)   not null,
  sbu_name      varchar2(250 char)  not null,
  constraint sbus_pk primary key (id)
    using index (create index sbus_px on sbus (id))
);
```

What is with the invalid table name error!  And why are the records not deleted!

Comment: *"Why are the records not deleted"* - generally, if Oracle issues an error message, it means it was not able to process your command - in which case (I'd hope) it did nothing.

Answer (score 3):

if what you are trying to accomplish is to empty the table the command is something like:

```
truncate sbus;
```

if you are trying to delete some rows:

```
delete from sbus where .....//put your condition
```

the * in your query is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
DELETE FROM sbus;
```

(without star "*")